# Google Fabric: UiAutomation not connected

Tags: android, crashlytics, google-fabric

After deployment of an app to Google Play Beta I see next issue in Crashlytics (6 - 7 users are affected)

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalStateException: UiAutomation not connected!
   at android.app.UiAutomation.throwIfNotConnectedLocked(UiAutomation.java:971)
   at android.app.UiAutomation.disconnect(UiAutomation.java:237)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.finish(Instrumentation.java:222)
   at android.support.test.runner.MonitoringInstrumentation.finish(MonitoringInstrumentation.java:351)
   at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.finish(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:405)
   at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:394)
   at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1960)
```

It seems that it's google test devices. 
Any ideas about fix?

Comment: We contacted Fabric support two days ago, no answer for now ...

Comment: any news on this one? Same here. Thanks.

Comment: nothing new, they do not answer

Comment: same here , any news ?

Comment: Some update, engineer form Firebase responded to our mail, they look to the issue

Comment: I am seeing the same thing. Mine too look like Google test devices. Are you able to confirm the crashes don't exist outside of the Beta. i.e Final release?

Comment: The Google sample code seems to have the same issue given the open issue on the repo : https://github.com/googlesamples/android-testing/issues/89

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems that this crash is related to UI testing in your app. If you don't have any UI testing and there are only default settings which added automatically during creating the project, you should remove from your build.gradle  the line **testInstrumentationRunner** in defaultConfig

```
  defaultConfig {
   ....
   testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
}
```

and **androidTestCompile, testCompile** in dependencies

```
dependencies {
androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', 
{
    exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
})
testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
...
```

Comment: what about if u have tests o.O :D

Comment: Indeed what if you do have tests? I'm not convinced this will occur to average users as in their case the instrumentation runner should not be invoked. I believe its confined to Google test devices,  I would like confirmation on this though...

Comment: I removed those lines but still get that exception reported in production

Comment: I don't have any of those lines in build.gradle, but I'm starting to see the issue.

Answer (score 29):

It seems like **nothing to worry about** (don't rely on accepted answer and don't remove your tests) because crashes have been reported on creating *pre-launch report* for google play store where some UI automation tests were executed. If you track devices on which this error has occurred then you'll see that all paths lead to pre-launch report.

You can find out more about pre-launch report [here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/7002270?hl=en)

Answer (score 1):

One thing is sure: you have an issue on UI. In most cases this occurs when you show a progress dialog that keeps being displayed for too much time. In this case the Google crawler goes in timeout and raises an exception.
My advice is: **be sure to not block UI with infinite dialogs.**

Answer (score 1):

The funny thing is that I get this crash while my app is being tested by google before publishing. I really don't know what google team is doing.