# Pre-launch reports UiAutomation not connected error

Tags: java, android, developer-console

when I try to upload my APK to android market I get a pre-launch reports with the following error. It only happens with Samsung galaxy S9.

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: UiAutomation not connected!
    at android.app.UiAutomation.throwIfNotConnectedLocked(UiAutomation.java:1043)
    at android.app.UiAutomation.waitForIdle(UiAutomation.java:647)
    at android.support.test.uiautomator.r.a(QueryController.java:36)
    at android.support.test.uiautomator.r.c(QueryController.java:32)
    at android.support.test.uiautomator.r.a(QueryController.java:9)
    at android.support.test.uiautomator.y.g(UiDevice.java:91)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.uiautomator.UiAutomatorScreenStateBuilder.getCurrentActivity(UiAutomatorScreenStateBuilder.java:39)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.uiautomator.UiAutomatorStateExtractor.getCurrentActivity(UiAutomatorStateExtractor.java:34)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.platform.hybrid.HybridStateExtractor.getCurrentActivity(HybridStateExtractor.java:31)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.controller.remote.RemotePlatform.handlePerformActionMessage(RemotePlatform.java:25)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.controller.remote.RemotePlatform.access$300(RemotePlatform.java:91)
    at androidx.test.tools.crawler.controller.remote.RemotePlatform$ControllerMessageHandler.handleMessage(RemotePlatform.java:8)
```

I don't think this is related to my code because I run the app without problems in the Android Studio emulator.

Any help with this?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54824152/1276636) answers your query.